# Llamar a una clase que concentra todos los autowired

Tags: java, spring-mvc

En mi proyecto en cada controller que programó tengo que colocar los @Autowired de cada clase service para poder obtener los métodos, pero me parece que esta forma de hacerlo no es la correcta entonces cree una clase llamada autowiredall la cual concentra todos los @Autowired para que luego sean usados por mis clases controller, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema de da porque cuando ejecutó el proyecto es como que no lee la clase que aloja todos los @Autowired haciendo que vuelva a colocar en cada controller toda la lista de autowired, alguien me puede mencionar si mi idea está bien? Y de estar bien tendrán algún ejemplo de comer implementarlo

Comment: ¿Tu clase `AutowiredAll` también la controla Spring? Es decir, ¿la has configurado como `@Service` o `@Component`?

Comment: Meter los @Autowired en cada clase es lo habitual. Ahora bien, si resulta que tienes clases que dependen de muchas otras clases (ya sean `@Autowired` o no) puede ser un problema de diseño y que estés haciendo clases que hacen demasiadas cosas (la idea general es que cada clase tiene una responsabilidad/cosa de la que se encarga). Cuidado que digo "**puede** ser", las cuestiones de diseño son algo más abiertas y opinables que las de simple programación. Más información https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica

Comment: No a mi clase AutowiredAll no la he configurado ni como Service ni como Component, aquí te mando un ejemplo del código que estoy usando en la clase AutowiredAll: public class AutowiredAll {
 
 @Autowired
    public SunarpInmuebleService sunarpInmuebleService;}